# Route Parameters laravel issue

Tags: laravel

I simply made this but `/maps/{category}/{map}` does not work correctly.

putting anything on `{category}` showing same result.

```
/maps/php/1
/maps/laravel/1
```

I want to show a result when category's name and map's id exactly matches otherwise redirect to homepage.

My route

```
Route::get('/maps/{category}', 'MapsController@index');
Route::get('/maps/{category}/{map}', 'MapsController@show');
```

My controller

```
public function show(Category $category, Map $map)
{        
    return view('maps.show', compact('map'));
}
```

My blade template

```
{{ $map->title }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap over the routes in your routes file so that the more specific one is first.

```
Route::get('/maps/{category}/{map}', 'MapsController@show');
Route::get('/maps/{category}', 'MapsController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/maps/{category}', 'MapsController@index');
```

is a more generalized route so it matches more than

```
Route::get('/maps/{category}/{map}', 'MapsController@show');
```

You should list the show route first.

To match an exact model attribute (i.e. name), you should customize the resolution logic the router uses in the route service provider boot method. For example:

```
Route::bind('category', function ($value) {
    return App\Category::where('name', $value)->first();
});
Route::bind('map', function ($value) {
    return App\Map::where('id', $value)->first();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need to swap order of routes if you are using 5.4, since I started with 5.4 to use laravel i cannot say anything for previous versions.

If you you want to filter asked map if it matches given category, you can use "whereHas" method with eloquent if you defined relationship between category and map.

"One To Many (Inverse)" relationship is what you need to use, check here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

And querying relationship is what you need to know, check here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

How your relationship should look like in Map model:

```
/**
 * Get the category that owns the map.
 */
 public function category()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
 }
```

An example code:

```
public function show($category, $map)
{        
    $map = Map::whereHas('category',function($query) use($category){
         $query->where('id', $category);
    });

    return view('maps.show', compact('map'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show($category,$map)
{        
    $category  = App\Category::where('category_name',$category);

    $map_id =App\Map::where('map_id',$map);
    if(!empty($category) && !empty($map_id))
    {
     return view('maps.show', compact('map'));
    }
    else
    {
      return view('homepage', compact('map'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).